# Drupal 9 No result message in search form

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-9

I added 'No result behavior' in the view and it shows up right away. How can I make this message appear only after clicking on the Submit button and if there are no search results?
Drupal 9.3, Using the Search API.

I need to display this message if there are no search results. Maybe there is a better way than using 'No result behavior'?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default when you open a view page, Drupal shows a "first search". If you already don't have any results on this view, Drupal shows the "no results" message you have defined.

For example, on a view listing of all news on your website, if a user searches for a keyword that doesn't exist, Drupal will show the "no results" message.

It is not logical to show an empty page when an user accesses it, because the user won't search anything if you don't have anything to show on that view. That's why Drupal shows the "no results" message when you open the page.

Answer (score 0):

I added a text area in 'No result behavior' and just delete it when necessary in hook_preprocess_views_view__VIEWID:

```
if (empty($variables['rows']) && empty($_GET['search_api_fulltext'])) {
  unset($variables['empty']['area']);
}
```